# How to get a local variable value (inside a function) with Jint?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, jint

In C# and using Jint, how can I get value of a local defined variable in a JavaScript function?

For example, I have the following JavaScript code in the string "testStr".
And I can't modify JS code as it is dynamic and not generated by me.

```
var globalVar = 5;

function myFunc(a, b) {

    var localVar1 = { "Hello" : 987 };

    var localVar2 = a + b;

    return;
}
```

And given the following C# code:

```
jintEngine.Execute(testStr);

// the following method do not exist in Jint, just here for example...
var valueStr = jintEngine.GoToFunc("myFunc").GetValue("localVar1").ToString();
```

And get the `localVar1` value as string.

Thanks!

Comment: If you find yourself wanting to do that, there is something wrong with your design. Maybe you should _return_ that value?

Comment: @Fildor -  js code is a third party code! not mine.

Comment: So, you have no way to modify it, I see. That info would be good to be added in the question. Still seems a little fishy, though. Don't you have a clean way to obtain that value?

Comment: hoisting moves `var` to the top of the scope. Maybe you can find your variable there.